# How to stop the header from reloading in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a small problem which is dependent on browser. If you open this link, `http://mazzeyprod-env-wbyfpn2srt.elasticbeanstalk.com/` in chrome and mozilla firefox you can see that in Mozilla Firefox if click on any buttons on the header the page smoothly transitions but if you do the same in Chrome, it reloads the entire page. But in Mozilla the Header always stays on the page. Can anyone help me how can I fix it ?

Comment: See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125997

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript on the buttons in the header?  Can you post that code here?

Comment: maybe irrelevant but an error is shown on the console "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"  in both browsers

Comment: This is what I did http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026731/how-to-open-new-page-without-refresh

Answer (score 0):

Both browsers are loading the pages as you navigate. It happens that ff does not make it apparent when reloading parts whose content remains the same. To notice the reloading you may use firebug or dev tools of ff and change the color of a menu link, once you navigate to another page the menu link will be reloaded and the color will be reverted.

Comment: So is there anyway that I can make it look like the ff in chrome as well

Comment: @HrishikeshSardar I'm afraid not, it is clearly a behaviour of ff. It is something that may stop happening in the future, or that may start happening in some other browser.