# How to open new page without refresh

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I am using a rails application, in which I am trying to open a new page, all the static page, `https://www.mazzey.com/` is the link, if you click on the header buttons, it opens new page with fade in and fade out effect with the header and footer without refreshing in Mozilla Firefox but in Google Chrome the header also refreshes. I also found that that header and footer refreshes in Firefox as well but it does not that unlike Google Chrome. So can I use to Ajax or any plugin to do that to avoid refresh of header and footer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    var newHash      = '',
        $mainContent = $("#main-content");
    $(".nav").delegate("a","click",function(){
        window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
        return false;
    });
    $(window).bind('hashchange',function(){
        newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);
        if(newHash){
            $mainContent.find("#guts").fadeOut('slow',function(){
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts",function(){
                    $mainContent.fadeIn('slow');
                });
            });
        }

    });
    $(window).trigger("hashchange");
});
```

This what I am using with the ba-hashchange plugin

for more information check this
css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/85-best-practices-dynamic-content/